# How to convert date time format as YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS from an confused datetime format using python?

Tags: python, csv

I am getting an date and time format as follows,

```
2019-1-31.23.54. 53. 207000000 
2019-1-31.23.51. 27. 111000000
```

I need to convert it as follows using python pandas,

```
2019-01-31 23:54:53
2019-01-31 23:51:27
```

How can get the expected result.

I tried to delete the last micro second value by convert the above text to csv based on space separated. Then delete the last column which contains microsecond.
But not able to convert  "2019-1-31.23.54." part.
Tried code,

```
df = pd.read_csv('file:///C:/prod/orderip.txt',sep='\s+',header=None)
df.columns = [ 'DateTime', 'Extra1','Extra2']
df.to_csv('C:/prod/data_out2.csv',index=False)
df = df.drop('Extra1', 1)
df = df.drop('Extra2', 1)
```

I need the DateTime column as follows,

```
2019-01-31 23:54:53
2019-01-31 23:51:27
```

Comment: How are you getting this format?

Comment: getting by an simulation data generator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pd.to_datetime` to convert to datetime format of your choice.

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(filename,sep='\s+',header=None)
df.columns = [ 'DateTime', 'Extra1','Extra2']
df.drop(['Extra2'], inplace=True, axis=1)

df["DateTime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DateTime"] + df['Extra1'].astype(int).astype(str), format="%Y-%m-%d.%H.%M.%S")
df.drop(['Extra1'], inplace=True, axis=1) 

print(df)
df.to_csv('C:/prod/data_out2.csv',index=False)

#or using df.pop
#df["DateTime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DateTime"] + df.pop('Extra1').astype(int).astype(str), format="%Y-%m-%d.%H.%M.%S") 
#df.to_csv(filename_1,index=False)
```

**Output:**

```
             DateTime
0 2019-01-31 23:54:53
1 2019-01-31 23:51:27
```

Answer (score 2):

The standard `datetime.strptime` should work in this case, just that the last 9 digits should be reduced to 6, since microseconds can only have 6 digits

```
import datetime

print(datetime.datetime.strptime('2019-1-31.23.54. 53. 207000', '%Y-%m-%d.%H.%M. %S. %f'))
```

The output will be

```
2019-01-31 23:54:53.207000
```

Comment: Python datetime library is a very strait forward. I think this is the best solution, comparing to the others explained in here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try first to converted to a standard datetime format with `pd.to_datetime`

```
>>> print(dates)
['2019-1-31.23.54.', '2019-1-31.23.51.']

>>> pd.to_datetime(dates, format='%Y-%m-%d.%H.%M.')
DatetimeIndex(['2019-01-31 23:54:00', '2019-01-31 23:51:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```